# How to fix this error message "Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token"

Tags: ios, ionic4, xcode10, ionic-native

I'm using ionic `4` with `FCM` to get notifications, everything works well on android but not on iOS. I'm facing this message on `xcode` console

> "5.7.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002023] The object  does not respond to
>   -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:.  Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided  with an FCM token"

Comment: If you need some more details, please let me know

Comment: Did you find the way to fix it man? I am having the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

The message basically means that your **FIRMessagingDelegate** should implement the following method to be able to receive **fcmToken** by Firebase. **fcmToken** is usually used as a recipient identificator, i.e. to who you want send messages

```
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken;
```

For example, you have a *FirebaseMessagingManager* class that works with Firebase Messaging then you could implement it in the following way:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>

@interface FirebaseMessagingManager : NSObject<MessagingDelegate>

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
}

@end
```

Comment: I already have this method in FIRMessaging.h, is it possible that something else is causing this error?

Comment: The .h does not provide an implementation. You'll have to write the code for this method yourself.

Comment: Where should I write it?

Comment: As part of the implementation of your `FIRMessagingDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to method to your appdelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) 
   // let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    UserDefaults.standard.set(deviceToken, forKey: "devToken")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(deviceToken, forKey: "devTokenString")
```

Comment: if you already have this method, try validating first you already have received a device token before making a request.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the bugs opened on this issue I found the solution for IOS 12+.
You simply need to add the following lines to your config.xml under the ios section:

```
<config-file parent="UIBackgroundModes" target="*-Info.plist">
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

You can read more here: [cordova-plugin-firebase Issue 788](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/788#issuecomment-428022830)

Also don't forget to request notification permissions by calling `Firebase.grantPermission();`